# Set value of a scoped variable in callback / closure

Tags: javascript

I have a very large JS script with many functions, callbacks and so on... one of my first actions is to obtain a value from an Ajax call. This value I then set to a global variable defined at the start of my script so I can reference the value again and again... the value with determine the user language for instance.

```
// define my global var at the top of my script..
var globalOpCo = "";

// I then try to give this a value in the next function I call...
$.ajax({
        url:"getURL",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            if(data === null){
            // do something...  
            }else{
            // set the current language...
                globalOpCo = data.Opco.toLowerCase();
                console.log(globalOpCo); // this is the value I want it to be from data.Opco.toLowerCase() 
                // now do something.... 
            }
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
```

Now later in my script I wish to pass the `globalOpCo` to another function like so...

```
 $("#aButton").on("click", function(){
        anotherFunction(globalOpCo); // I want to pass the globalOpCo as an arguement but its value isn't get updated above?
    });
```

however the value of `globalOpCo` is an empty string! The #aButton cannot be clicked before or until the ajax call above is run. Can someone help?

Comment: If you console log out globalOpCo after the ajax call what do you see?

Comment: Since you claim that the button is clicked after the response was received, there must be another problem. Maybe scope? Please created a minimal, complete http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Okay, I have worked this out...! It is scope, the variable is defined within $("document").ready(function(){}) whilst the function that is calling it is outside $("document").ready(function(){})

Comment: An explicit `window.globalOpCo` would avoid scoping issues.

Answer (score 2):

Disable your button by default, add your onclick in your success function, after you define globalOpCo, and enable it when you set the onclick. Bonus: now it doesn't need to be global anymore, since the code that needs it is right next to it. Which is good =)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I may have worked this out! It is scope, the variable is defined within `$("document").ready(function(){})` whilst the function that is calling it is outside `$("document").ready(function(){})`

Comment: then you'll want to change your original question to show you're defining a scoped variable (by using "var") inside document.ready - right now the post claims that variable is declared globally at the top of the script =)

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are just properties on the global object, which is `window` in browsers. You can avoid scoping issues by explicitly using `window.globalOpCo`.